# Azure API Management - Changing URL for Function App causes 404

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management

I've added my function app to API Management in Azure.

My function app has an undesirable name `swanky-function-app` - and I want to change it.

When API management mounts it, it gives it a default URI of `/swanky-function-app` which is undesirable.

[image]

When I change the URL field to something nicer such as `/some-new-path`, when I test it, it 404s.

How do I customize the URL without it 404ing?

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting up in APIM, you just need to est the url suffix value if you want to change the url,

[image]

Comment: Tried this - it still generates URLs with the function app name in the URI. E.g. in your example the URI comes out at https://apimgtest.azure-api.net/test/swanky-function-app

Answer (score 0):

You can add a URL rewrite policy. Select the operation, go to "Inbound processing", add policy, choose "rewrite-uri". Fill in the original route in the backend field, for frontend it should already show the URL that you chose in the Frontend URL settings (shown in window above)

I don't think that's the way it should be, but at least it works